# Sort unordered list based on data-row and data-col

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with a 'ul' (unordered list) that I insert 'li' elements on the fly. With 2 attributes: data-col and data-row. This two attributes are arbitrary and can be any value. (any Real positive number)

Is there a way to re-order all 'li' elements based on data-row and data-col?
It does not have to be visible, I just need the 'ul' element with all its children properly ordered.

Extra info:
The reason for this is because I have a back-end code that needs to read this 'ul' element with its children in sequence and then populate a TABLE element.
It´s like I´m saving a multi-dimensional array into a 1 dimension array.

Thanks :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to sort the data you're sending to the backend, and not the elements themselves ? Maybe you should post some of the code, or at least a few examples of what it would look like ?

Comment: Are the rows/columns even ? If you have any code that you're kicking around it would be easier to assist!

Comment: @adeneo I´m using a grid framework so it´s kinda big code, as I insert new things to the grid, the framework adds a new 'li' to the 'ul' element. But it does not rearrange it, it adds to the bottom of the list. I haven´t thought about reorder it in backend, I just thought it would be easy to reorder it in javascript. I will try it but I´d still like to know how to do it in javascript.

Comment: @zfrisch No, max columns are 4 but the rows are variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.sort()` to sort the list of `li` elements based on row, then column, and re-append the sorted list to the `ul`.  The appended list replaces the previous unsorted version:

```js
var ul = $('#mylist');

var lis = $('#mylist > li');

lis.sort(

  function(a, b) {
    var ela = $(a);
    var elb = $(b);
    
    var res = +ela.data('row') - elb.data('row');
    
    if (res == 0)   // if rows are the same, sort by column
      res = +ela.data('col') - elb.data('col');
    
    return res;
  }

).appendTo(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="mylist">
  <li data-col="2" data-row="14">14, 2</li>
  <li data-col="2" data-row="1">1, 2</li>
  <li data-col="3" data-row="4">4, 3</li>
  <li data-col="1" data-row="3">3, 1</li>
  <li data-col="1" data-row="4.5">4.5, 1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, that was perfect! Thanks Paul!